# Problem with shared library path referenced by ndk binary

Tags: android-ndk

What I want to test is the Android NDK JNI called in the following order: C (NDK binary) -> java -> C (shared library). So, I wrote an NDK binary (JNI_src.c) included the shared library (jnitest.so) and ran it on Android. but, at runtime the linker cannot find the shared library jnitest.so used by JNI_src.

```
08-27 10:29:16.416  1121  1121 F linker  : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/JNI_output": library "./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libjnitest.so" not found
```

The following is the C code and Makefile I wrote (NDK Binary, shared library).

JNI_src.c Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void shared_func();
int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "hello");

    // create JNI variable
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM  *jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;            // env variables to control invocation
    JavaVMOption options[4];
    jint res;
    jstring jstr;
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;
    jobjectArray args;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);
    if(res < 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "cnunsrtest", "Can't create Java VM");
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create Java VM\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Hello");
    if(cls == 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "cnunsrtest", "Can't find Hello class");
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't find Hello class\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/STring;])V");
    if(mid == 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "cnunsrtest", "Can't find Hello.main");
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't find Hello.main\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello, World!");
    if(jstr == 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "cnunsrtest", "Out of memory1");
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory1\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 1,
            (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), jstr);
    if(args == 0){
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "cnunsrtest", "Out of memory2");
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory2\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid, args);
    
    shared_func();
    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);

    return 0;
}
```

jnitest.so (jnitest.c)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void shared_func()
{
    printf("shared func cnunsr");
}
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL java_Hello_jnifunc(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    printf("Java call cnunsr");
    shared_func();
    return;
}
```

Code that built the shared library before make .

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -I/home/juno/jdk1.8.0_301/include -I/home/juno/jdk1.8.0_301/include/linux -o libjnitest.so jnitest.c -shared -fPIC
```

After building the shared library, run the Makefile to get the executable.
Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jvm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SYSROOT)/home/juno/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/aarch64/server/libjvm.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jnitest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SYSROOT)/home/juno/Desktop/nkd/libjnitest.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := JNI_output
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := JNI_src.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := jnitest jvm
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I copied the executable file and shared library to Android and ran it. But the linker could not find the shared library. I think the cause is incorrect information about the library in the NDK binary. (./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libjnitest.so)

Therefore, readelf was used. (readelf --all JNI_output)

```
...
Dynamic section at offset 0xdd0 contains 33 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libjnitest.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjvm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x650
...
```

As expected, the dynamic section of libjvm.so is normal, but the dynamic section of libjnitest.so contains an odd path. What part of the Android.mk needs to be modified? I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path where libjnitest.so exists, but the same error occurs.